# Is CSS text-transform "expensive"

Tags: css, performance, transform

Is CSS `text-transform` expensive in terms of processing? It appears to me that the browser's being forced to do some work that it wouldn't normally need to (*if you didn't transform*), but is that a significant amount of processing? Does it impact performance at all?

Comment: why do you think text-transform is expensive?  How did you measure that?

Comment: I didn't say it *was* expensive - I just asked the question...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It might take a bit more processing from the client's browser, but this will be totally insignificant unless you're transforming pages and pages of text (and if you're doing that, you're doing something wrong).

You also have the overhead of having the CSS property written in your stylesheet (heavier file), but once again it's only a few characters and shouldn't make any difference.

---

I got curious so I ran some basic benchmarks. On Firefox 3 I displayed a page with 200 paragraphs of Lorem Lipsum.

Rendering it will take between **0.150s to 0.175s**

When adding `text-transform:none` I don't see any significant difference.

When adding `text-transform:uppercase` it now takes between **0.350s and 0.380s**

When adding `text-transform:capitalize` it now takes between **0.320s and 0.350s**

When adding `text-transform:lowercase` it now takes between **0.320s and 0.350s**

So apparently we do have some overheads processing this, but once again I'm capitalizing hundreds of lines and it only costs 0.2s. Therefore if I were you I'd use it without thinking about performance too much unless you want to text-transform huge chunks of text.

Comment: Well, that *is* significant. A good example of why performance matters in stylesheets, too (if you take the cummulative aspect into account).

Comment: @boldewyn It is significant if you try to uppercase a whole text, but if you only use it for "classic" purposes, you shouldn't worry about it

Comment: @marcgg: What I mean, is, that it will sum up. Many people smile at articles telling about bad selector style, but as you can see, a single line of CSS can double the rendering speed.

Comment: @boldewyn: true. CSS shouldn't be underestimated when it comes to performances, but in most cases the impact would be so minimal it isn't important. Of course my example demonstrates otherwise but it is a pretty extreme example ^^

Comment: I'd say "it could be significant", depending on your application. if you had a big list of things - an email app, or blog listing, etc. - and you transformed every title, the, as this post shows, that could affect performance. But, as you say, it you just use it for the odd thing here and there, probably no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @marcgg: Out of curiosity, what processor model/speed do you have? I'm wondering if you have a really slow or fast one, to help judge that benchmark.

Comment: I guess you'd have to compare it with the same procedure on the server side for a complete reference. The text has to be processed somewhere.

Comment: @thirtydot I have a 1 year old iMac. 3Ghz Core 2 Duo, 4GB of ram.

Answer (score 4):

If you're designing for mobile, every little bit helps.  If it's not dynamic, then type it out in uppercase

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason why it should be any more 'expensive' than any other CSS style. All it does is convert a string to upper/lower case, which is hardly the most taxing process a computer can be asked to do.

I'd compare it with displaying in italics or bold; both these styles effectively change the font for the entire string, but you wouldn't consider not using them in case it's processor intensive for the browser, would you?

The only time you could even conceivably think of `text-transform` as having a hard time would be if you're using a non-latin character set, in which case converting to upper/lower case may not make sense. But you can be pretty sure the brower makers have got that covered. (and in any case, if you're in that position, why would you even want to use `text-transform`?)

Comment: The difference between `font-style:italic` and `text-transform-uppercase` is, that the latter must *change* the actual character data to be displayed. It's not just selecting a different font and letting the font renderer do its work.

Comment: @Boldewyn Perhaps you know some implementation details of browsers. I don't know relevant details and so would have assumed, changing a character code to be cheaper than changing the font. Changing font would have to introduce some kind of font change, probably allocating memory, in the first place. Overwriting a single character code looks cheaper a priori to me.

Comment: Do you have a reference for what you say about the browsers being able to handle `text-transform` on non-latin characters? I keep the same css for non-latin characters and just leave the same text-transform rule on. I want to just know that this is safe and defined and wont break anything. To reiterate: it's working correctly (ie: English text is capitalized and non-latin is not), I just want to make sure this happens in all cases.

Comment: @theyuv the answer was written almost a decade ago. If I did have any references at the time, they certainly wouldn't be relevant now.